# getting error while opning razorpay payment geteway

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, razorpay

getting error java.lang.SecurityException: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts for android 14. this is my

```
<receiver
 android:name="com.razorpay.RzpTokenReceiver"
 android:exported="true"
 android:permission="">
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="rzp.device_token.share" />
 </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue with the `java.lang.SecurityException` related to receivers in Android 14. I found that updating the Rezorpay dependency to its latest version resolved the problem for me.

Make sure to check your [Rezorpay dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.razorpay/razorpay-java) in your project and update it to the latest version. This might help you overcome the `SecurityException` issue. Let me know if this resolves your problem